# Spring Boot Related Enity not being saved correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

Implementing Authentication by creating a `User` and `Authority` class as follows:

**Authority**

```java
package com.blog.blog.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**User**

```java
package com.blog.blog.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String pwd;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private String createdAt;

//    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Authority> authorities;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

}
```

My Controller to save the `User` looks like this:

```java
package com.blog.blog.controller;
// ...

@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    public RegistrationController(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User userRequest){


        User u = userRepo.save(userRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(u, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON payload:

```json
{
    "name": "aa",
    "email": "2aa@mail.com",
    "mobileNumber": 1999,
    "pwd": "password",
    "authorities": [        
        { "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"}
    ]
}
```

Problem:

In db `User` record are populated but `Authority` record is not associated with the `User` record:

This is how it looks:

[image]

When I check the logs, I see that while inserting the `Authority` record `user_id` points to `null`.

```bash
2024-02-04T12:00:57.803+05:30 TRACE 661939 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter (1:INTEGER) <- [4]
2024-02-04T12:00:57.810+05:30 DEBUG 661939 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into authorities (name,user_id) values (?,?)
2024-02-04T12:00:57.810+05:30 TRACE 661939 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter (1:VARCHAR) <- [ROLE_ADMIN]
2024-02-04T12:00:57.810+05:30 TRACE 661939 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter (2:INTEGER) <- [null]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a bidirectional `@OneToMany` association, both sides of the association need to be synchronized to ensure data consistency. That means the child entities have to know about the parent entity to be able to set the correct foreign key (`user_id`).

The `register` method should be changed to the following:

```java
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User userRequest){
    userRequest.getAuthorities().forEach(i -> i.setUser(userRequest));
    User u = userRepo.save(userRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(u, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Usually, two utility methods, as shown below, are defined on the parent side that automatically synchronizes the child side.

```java
public void addAuthority(Authority authority) {
    authorities.add(authority);
    authority.setUser(this);
}
 
public void removeAuthority(Authority authority) {
    authorities.remove(authority);
    authority.setUser(null);
}
```

For reference: [The best way to map a `@OneToMany` relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: thanks man, I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

As Toni already mentioned, you need to link the user to each authority like

```
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User userRequest){
    userRequest.getAuthorities().forEach(authority -> authority.setUser(userRequest));
    User u = userRepo.save(userRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(u, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Additionally to avoid a circle reference, you already suggested correctly, that you will need a JsonIgnore. In this case you need it in the Authority class like:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

Hope that helps